# using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am getting an error:

> One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName.

I haven't even saved any data to Core Data yet.

The property that has type Transformable, 'notificationIdentifiers', is of type NSObject in my NSManagedObject subclass. Why is the error saying it is unset or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName?

I also get the warning:

> CoreData: warning: Property 'notificationIdentifiers' on Entity 'Affirmation' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer.  Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead.

Here is my NSManagedObject subclass:

```
extension Affirmation {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Affirmation> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Affirmation>(entityName: "Affirmation")
    }

    @NSManaged public var body: String
    @NSManaged public var count: Int64
    @NSManaged public var days: NSData
    @NSManaged public var frequency: Int64
    @NSManaged public var notificationIdentifiers: NSObject
    @NSManaged public var recordName: String?
    @NSManaged public var time: NSDate
    @NSManaged public var timestamp: NSDate
    @NSManaged public var title: String

}
```

When I change that property to be of type NSSecureUnarchiveFromData in my NSManagedObject subclass, I get an error saying:

> Use of undeclared type 'NSSecureUnarchiveFromData'

I did a search on Google and I get no results telling me which library framework Use of undeclared type 'NSSecureUnarchiveFromData' belongs to. I did a search at developer.apple.com and it doesn't find anything on it.

I don't think I am understanding exactly what this message is saying.

Here is my entire debug window:

```
2020-04-09 14:43:34.107774-0500 Affirmations[3922:921109] [error] fault: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
CoreData: fault: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
2020-04-09 14:43:34.108286-0500 Affirmations[3922:921109] [error] CoreData: One or more models in this application are using transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset, or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.
CoreData: warning: Property 'notificationIdentifiers' on Entity 'Affirmation' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer.  Please switch to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead.
```

Other similar posts have not helped me. I am unable to follow the solutions given, and no conclusive solutions are given anyway.

Comment: Did you try `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` or the class name `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`?

Comment: @Willeke Not yet. I will try that.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem by selecting the Attribute and setting the Transformer property in the Data Model Inspector to "NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer".

Comment: Sorry i know this is an old question but where is this option in xcode? Im getting this exact error but there are no references when i search for NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName

Comment: I don't think it would show on a search. The Data Model inspector would be on the right-hand side of the Xcode window -- to the side where your right hand is when you're facing the screen. You have to be sure you select the Attribute. I don't remember what that is called that allows you to see the Attributes, but I remember there was a window that was where the editor window usually is.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this warning was being thrown by an old version of Google Analytics